# Failed to sign Mac OS X app

Tags: java, xcode, macos, codesign

I am running this lines of code to sign my app of Java application on Mac OS X -

```
#!/bin/sh
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
codesign -s "my name" my.app
codesign -v -v my.app  && echo my.app is Signed Successfully!
```

I have written these all lines into one sh (SignApp.sh) file and running this sh file on creating app successfully to sign in my build.xml file as -

```
<target name="SigningApp">
      <exec executable="/bin/sh">
          <arg value="SignApp.sh"/>
     </exec>
</target>
```

The same lines to sign app work fine at my system always successfully.

My app is created at another server machine. But sometime it sign my app successfully with this lines of code, and sometime it do not,  I get these message on verification of app using this command `codesign -v -v my.app` -

```
my.app: code object is not signed at all
In architecture: x86_64
```

One more thing is that running these below lines on command prompt manually sign the app -

```
  export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
  codesign -s "my name" my.app
```

Comment: I have the same problem since upgrading to Mavericks, unclear whether this is a Mavericks issue, General Update issue or Xcode 5 issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the --deep option

```
codesign --deep -s "my name" my.app
```

That has just built without errors for me, just going to upload and redownload to see if it really has worked.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your suggestions!! Please suggest me what are the changes needed to sign app if XCode and Mac both are updated (means do --deep and codesign_allocate path need to change?).

Comment: @Neelam I didn't have to change codedesign allocate path but mine was already set to the value in the other answer, I just added the --deep parameter

Comment: By using --deep option in signing app well but this not launching app at mac, because of broken or changed framework, how can I get signed working app on mavericks - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190177/how-to-preserve-alias-property-while-signing-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186202/how-to-sign-app-on-mavericks-with-xcode-5-0-2

Comment: I have resolved my problem by updating jdk7u21 to jdk7u45, details -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190177/how-to-preserve-alias-property-while-signing-app

Comment: Well, I guess I had to upgrade that also!

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently updated your Xcode version (let says in 5.0.1 for instance) you might have to change location of codesign_allocate environment variable to:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate`

see [blog.hoachuck.biz](http://blog.hoachuck.biz/blog/2013/10/29/codesign-useful-info-in-xcode-5-dot-0-1/)