# How to sign app on Mavericks with Xcode 5.0.2?

Tags: java, xcode, osx-mavericks, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I am trying to sign my java app on Mavericks OS using Xcode 5.0.2 -

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate" ]; then
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
elif [ -f "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate" ]; then
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
else
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
fi
codesign --deep -s "my name" MayApp.app
codesign -v MayApp.app && echo MayApp.app is Signed Successfully!
```

Earlier I have asked as [Unable to launch App built on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043127/unable-to-launch-app-built-on-mavericks) because at that time my machine was on Mountain Lion 10.8.2, but now I have Mavericks.
Now situation is similar to my server machine where we build app, as -

- Java : jdk7u21
- Xcode : 5.0.2

Still I am facing the same error on launching app i.e -

```
admins-iMac-4:~ admin$ open /Users/admin/Desktop/APP/MyApp.app 
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/admin/Desktop/APP/MyApp.app.
```

If I sign without **--deep** parameter then -

```
SigningApp:
     [exec] MayApp.app: code object is not signed at all
     [exec] In subcomponent: /Users/admin/Desktop/BUILD/MayApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk
     [exec] MayApp.app: code object is not signed at all
```

I have tried with multiple combinations to sign like but all are vain -

- codesign --deep -s "my name" MayApp.app
- codesign --force -s "my name" MayApp.app
- codesign --force -s "my name" MayApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk

Tried to sign jdk before signing app, but nothing happen with app.

Everything was working fine before Mavericks, earlier no need of using **--deep** parameter within signing statement required.

**If I am building app WITHOUT SIGNING app then it launching fine!!**

Please suggest any way of signing app at Mavericks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has been resolved by updating Java from jdk7u21 to latest jdk7u45, the detailed information added here - [How to preserve alias property while signing app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190177/how-to-preserve-alias-property-while-signing-app/20240418#20240418)

Thanks