# How to preserve alias property while signing app?

Tags: java, xcode, code-signing, osx-mavericks, codesign

I have created on JavaFX application app at Mavericks and signing with Xcode 5.0.2 using -

```
codesign --deep -s "my name" MayApp.app
codesign -v MayApp.app && echo MayApp.app is Signed Successfully!
```

WITHOUT SIGN MYAPP LAUNCHING FINE!!

Without using **--deep**, I am not able to sign app at Mavericks.

**-- More Try --**

Now at Mavericks, we can no longer sign a bundle if any nested bundle in that package is unsigned. I did sign the framework of my app by following the instruction written at - http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/

```
codesign --verbose --force --sign "my name" MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk
```

Signing framework commands alone or after signing framework, does not make any changes in signing app.

**------ THE MAIN ISSUE ------**

On running above commands (whether only sign app or along with framework signing), MyApp.app get signed successfully but that *app not launching at Mac because of signing command not preserving ALIAS property for the file **libjli.dylib** that exist at - `MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/MacOS`. Signing app code converting **libjli.dylib** alias into a Dynamic Library.*

Then I thought of copying libjli.dylib via following command -

```
<target name="Copylib" depends="SigningApp">
<delete file="MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib"/>
<exec executable="cp">
   <arg line="-R /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/MacOS/ MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/MacOS"/>
</exec>
</target>
```

This preserving alias but now on verifying sign app to says -

```
admins-iMac:osx admin$ codesign -v -v MyApp.app
MyApp.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk
In architecture: x86_64
```

Same happen if I am copying that alias manually at MyApp.app.

Please suggest any way to sign app with preserving the properties of the all files exist in my framework at - **Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk**?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem get resolved by updating Java from jdk7u21 to latest jdk7u45 because Oracle's Java version 7u25 and below have been disabled by Apple on OS X. Updating to the latest release will allow Java to be run on Mac OS X.

Additionally, I have to made these changes to make app valid to sign -

1. In *MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist* for **CFBundleExecutable** to MyApp, **CFBundleIconFile** to MyApp.icns.
2. Need to copy **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib** to **MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/MacOS** for **libjli.dylib** alias.
3. We also need to copy **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Info.plist** from system installed jdk to our **MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/**

**Note:** Step-2 and 3 are required because on deploying JavaFx app, the deployment process only copying `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home` by default into *MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns*, it was skipping MacOS/ folder and Info.plist.

Without doing these above changes for signing app with -

```
codesign --deep -s "my name" MayApp.app
```

I was getting erron on signing - ***MyApp.app: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable - We are facing this issue so we need to identify about what are making app bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable.***

Thanks

Comment: I wonder whether this solution applicable to my case of trying to sign a java app under mountain lion. It keeps saying, 'Code already signed', but when checked it  says invalid signed attribute.. :( I'll report here on the result after upgrading JDK

Comment: @swdev please let me know what is the xcode and java version at your Mountain Lion OS X before upgrade?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Neelam, the solution is quite simple. I just use `codesign -f -s "Eko Wibowo"`, forcing to signed it, regarding whether the package was signed or not. Actually, I haven't signed it. But, using that `-f` option solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I still get an error after applying the workaround suggested. Once there is a symlink, app verification doesn't come through. Used `spctl -a -v MyApp.app` command line to verify the bundle.

I dug deeper and found that GetJREPath method relies on libjli.dylib file location. Once it's moved into Contents/MacOS/ folder, everything is broken. I made a little change to the GetJREPath method and rebuilt JDK from sources. Here is a file difference to apply it to your build:

```
diff -r ff67c8965852 src/macosx/bin/java_md_macosx.c
--- a/src/macosx/bin/java_md_macosx.c   Wed Dec 11 11:19:00 2013 -0800
+++ b/src/macosx/bin/java_md_macosx.c   Wed Dec 18 17:33:29 2013 +0400
@@ -640,7 +640,7 @@
         return JNI_FALSE;
     }

-    const char lastPathComponent[] = "/lib/jli/libjli.dylib";
+    const char lastPathComponent[] = "/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib";
     size_t sizeOfLastPathComponent = sizeof(lastPathComponent) - 1;
     if (pathLen < sizeOfLastPathComponent) {
         return JNI_FALSE;
@@ -648,7 +648,11 @@

     size_t indexOfLastPathComponent = pathLen - sizeOfLastPathComponent;
     if (0 == strncmp(realPathToSelf + indexOfLastPathComponent, lastPathComponent, sizeOfLastPathComponent - 1)) {
-        realPathToSelf[indexOfLastPathComponent + 1] = '\0';
+        realPathToSelf[indexOfLastPathComponent + 10] = 'H';
+        realPathToSelf[indexOfLastPathComponent + 11] = 'o';
+        realPathToSelf[indexOfLastPathComponent + 12] = 'm';
+        realPathToSelf[indexOfLastPathComponent + 13] = 'e';
+        realPathToSelf[indexOfLastPathComponent + 14] = '\0';
         return JNI_TRUE;
     }
```

Here are building and packaging instructions for OpenJDK7: https://github.com/hgomez/obuildfactory/wiki/Building-and-Packaging-OpenJDK7-for-OSX

I filled a bug to Oracle as well. Hope this helps.